# keep keyboard open on Ionic when button click ( chat app )

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, android-softkeyboard

I have an Ionic v1 chat application, I made everything, but I encountred the famous problem when  clicking on a send button (send chat) the keyboard loses focus from the input and then closes.

I've tried many approaches, but it none of them work:

- Input directive to keep focus,
- forcing focus on click event,
- modifying the value of InputUserAction in config.xml to false.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<div class="sender">
<input type="text" ng-model="..." class="...">
<div class="button-send">
<span class="send-chat"><i class="ion ion-send"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try refocus the input you were in or install a keyboard plugin which lets you prevent default behavior

Comment: didn't work, when refocusing, the keyboard loses focus and it closes then opens again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use (mousedown)="sentMessage(); $event.preventDefault()"

```
<ion-button (mousedown)="sentMessage(); $event.preventDefault()">
      <ion-icon ios="ios-send" md="md-send"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

Comment: Works on Android, yet to test on iOS. +1 for the tip anway!

Comment: works on Android and iOS on ionic 6 ! Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

ALright found a fix!
for all of you out there, who are using ionic for a chat like app, and want the keyboard to stay focused after clicking on a button,

Just, replace the button by a label with for="inputID" like so:

```
<div class="sender">
<input id="inputID" type="text" ng-model="..." class="...">
<div class="button-send">
<label for="inputID" class="send-chat"><i class="ion ion-send"></i></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work great on IOS, as the keyboard goes down and up again, rather than staying up. Android i playing nice tho.

Comment: @Coo yeah iOS is just messed up, but by going to Ionic 3 all your problems are solved out of the box, glad that I migrated to it, give it a try

Comment: @Sletheren I'm using Ionic 3 too, how EXACTLY it solves this problem?

Comment: @Dimitri there's a thing called `inputBlurring` that you can set to false. This is the only way I've found around it. However, that prevents any normal tap anywhere on the page from putting down the keyboard, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Works like a charm - been stuck on this issue for 2 years! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(mousedown)="doSomething(); $event.preventDefault()"
```

works with latest Ionic version too.

Answer (score 0):

try the same code It will 100% work

```
<ion-input #input placeholder="Type a message.." (blur)="input.focus()">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try forcing the keyboard to open via it's cordova plugin
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard#keyboardshow

Comment: tried it, the keyboard closes and opens again, which is not good.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/81#issuecomment-278071581
I found this .. it may help