# Can mobile keypad always be opened in Ionic application?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I want to keep my mobile keypad always opened, after sending a message in Chat Page of Ionic chat application. Because on clicking send button, on first click, keypad goes down and then, on second click, message is sent. So, it takes time and shows lagginess in Ionic 3 app.

Is there any way to handle this issue of keypad in Ionic application (Ionic 3/4)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keep keyboard open on Ionic when button click ( chat app )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858201/keep-keyboard-open-on-ionic-when-button-click-chat-app)

Comment: Thankyou @Reactgular . I tried this solution, but didn't get any result. May be the issue and solution is for Ionic Version 1. But it isn't working in my Ionic 3 application.

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault() and stopPropagation()` are main concept which help in keeping keyboard open.
To get this functionality done, I added #sendButton to the Send Button of my chat page. And using ViewChild,

```
    @ViewChild('sendButton') private sendButton:Button;
```

Then, I added following code to my .ts page. And called this function on ngOnInit() (One can also use ionViewDidLoad() or ionViewWillLoad())

```
keepKeyboardVisible() {
    if(!!this.sendButton){
        let el = this.sendButton._elementRef.nativeElement;
        console.log(el);
        el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            this.stopBubble(event);
        });
        el.addEventListener('touchdown', (event) => {
            this.stopBubble(event);
        });
        el.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) => {
            this.stopBubble(event);
        });
        el.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
            this.stopBubble(event);
        });
        el.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => { //Triggered by a phone
            this.stopBubble(event);
            this.sendMessage();
        });
    }
}

stopBubble(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation(); //Stops event bubbling
}
```